Why does my Pydantic model contain an extra attribute when popupated from an object with extra=ignore?
The title says it all:
Why does my Pydantic model contain an extra attribute when popupated from an object with extra=ignore?
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict
# pydantic 2.4.2

class Test(BaseModel):

    a: int

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='ignore',
                              from_attributes=True)

class TestExtended(Test):

    b: float

m = TestExtended(a=2, b=2)

# Why does m_1 contain the additional field "b" even though 
# we try to instantiate Test with extra=ignore?
m_1 = Test.model_validate(m)
print(m_1)

The output shows that the model contains both attributes:
>>> a=2 b=2.0

Any ideas what the reason for this behaviour is?

Not an answer, but I think it's interesting that Test.model_validate(m) returns a TestExtended instance (try print(repr(m_1)) instead of print(m_1)).

That's really surprising behavior. I would ask this question in Pydantic's repository on GitHub

It works in a non-obvious way, but if you call model_validate with the subclass as an argument it will just return the subclass instance:
m_1 = Test.model_validate(m)
print(type(m_1))  # <class '__main__.TestExtended'>

By the way, it works as expected if you use it with something that isn't a subclass:
class AnotherModel(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: float

a = AnotherModel(a=1, b=3)

m_1 = Test.model_validate(a)
print(m_1)  # a=1
print(type(m_1))  # <class '__main__.Test'>

In your case, it would be better to do something like the following::
m_1 = Test(**m.dict()) # "ignore" works exactly as expected

print(m_1)  # a=2
print(type(m_1))  # <class '__main__.Test'>

